# Raspberry PI USB Webcam - Logitech Quickcam 9000

Tags: linux, video-streaming, webcam, raspberry-pi2

I have been trying to stream my webcam over http with a raspberry pi 2 using mjpg-streamer. It works to stream the webcam and also some of the image controls, like brightness, focus, etc...

What I cannot seem to get to work is the zoom controls on the logitech's QuickCam Pro 9000. On a windows PC with the logitech software, I am able to zoom in and out. Yet, using mjpg-streamer, I am unable to replicate this control.

I have looked at a lot of links include:

- http://www.slblabs.com/2012/09/26/rpi-webcam-stream/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/
- http://blog.philippklaus.de/2010/03/logitech-quickcam-pro-9000/
- http://sourceforge.net/p/mjpg-streamer/code/HEAD/tree/
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10496&p=124750
- https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer/tree/master/mjpg-streamer-experimental
- http://blog.cudmore.io/post/2015/03/15/Installing-mjpg-streamer-on-a-raspberry-pi/
- http://www.slblabs.com/2012/09/26/rpi-webcam-stream/

Yet, I have not been able to figure out the zoom control for the webcam. Anyone have any idea how to get the zoom controls working with mjpg-streamer or another video streamer for USB webcam for the raspberry pi?

Comment: This Q may be more appropriate on the related site http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Comment: Dump usb camera  signal(zoom) and resend to camera(pyusb on PI).

Comment: @dsgdfg: I like the idea and I have checked it out a bit. But, do you know a good way to get a dump of the usb zoom?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there are no zoom controls after all for the webcam. The windows software simply does a digital zoom on the video feed from the webcam.

If you would like this feature for mjpeg-streamer, then it may be an idea to use a javascript script to add some sort digital zoom controls for the video feed from the webcam in the browser.